# Tutorial for: "CiviCRM Event OG Config (sample)" Module

Tags: civievent

How does this integration work? What is required to set it up? Documentation is very sparse.

If we want every CiviEvent to have a corresponding OG with the participants synced - is this the solution? Or, is CiviRules/CiviEntity a better route?

Comment: Zac - don't quite understand your question. We have done custom work so that eg when you create an Event it sets up an OG, and when someone signs up for the Event via civi gets added to the OG. But I don't think we were able to publish the work at the time. Can't recall if it was all done via Rules - I don't think so.

Comment: I am referring to the Drupal Module I seem to have installed - not sure if it was from Civi Entity or just stock CiviCRM. Just curious what it does, and how it works.

Comment: how about you edit your answer and provide a link?

Comment: I found this: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC40/CiviCRM+vs.+Organic+Groups

Comment: Feels a bit like an archaeological dig ;-)

Comment: if you need OGs built off Events then it can be done but think that module may be way old

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution is via Drupal Rules as per this pretty ancient blog

https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/foray-rules-module

I know that since then we have rolled up modules for clients that deliver the various integrations along the lines of

- if Event has custom field = X then create an OG
- if a person with Event participant role Y is added to Event make then the OG Admin
- if a person registers for the event then create user (if not already have one) and add them to the OG.